# Chrome popups impossible to find

Tags: macos, google-chrome, expose

I have a MacBook Pro with two external monitors connected. I also use Spaces, so I have three displays visible at any time, and a couple of virtual desktops, and a couple of apps running full screen.

Every now and then Chrome will pop up a dialog somewhere that I can't see - sometimes it's off the screen, sometimes it's hidden behind another apps window, and sometimes I don't know where it is. If you don't find it and dismiss it, Chrome won't allow you to close tabs or windows, minimize or full-screen a window, or close Chrome.

Sometimes I can get the missing dialog back with some combination of command-tabbing between apps, or using F9 Expose to show all the displays. The "Show All Windows" option in the Dock icon *never* works. That's how I know what's causing the problem. But sometimes I can't find it for love nor money. When that happens, the only solution I've found is to Force Quit Chrome using option-click on the Dock icon.

Is there a better way to find this errant window?

(I had a look at [How can I find alert-type dialogs that prevent other windows of the same application to be focussed?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/166401/how-can-i-find-alert-type-dialogs-that-prevent-other-windows-of-the-same-applica) and those solutions don't work either.)

Comment: Best way is to not spread windows from one app across different Spaces, which is what I'm guessing you are doing.

Comment: That's not a solution, that's crippling myself to work around a bug in the OS. I have multiple Spaces for a reason.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)